# Linked List printea 0 en posicion inicial C++

Tags: c++, lista

Me di cuenta de que al momento de insertar (o hacer un append) a mi implementación de Linked List y luego invocar a getValue en la primera posición me retorna un 0, sin embargo al invocar un erase en la primera posición me elimina el numero que corresponde (por ejemplo 8).
Cabe recalcar de igual forma que al invocar moveToStart (o en su defecto, moveToPos(0)) igual me retorna un 0.

En un inicio tengo definida la clase de esta forma:

```
class tLista{
    private:
        tNodo* head;
        tNodo* tail;
        tNodo* curr; //Siempre apuntara al nodo anterior del actual
        
        unsigned int listSize;
        unsigned int pos;
        
    public:
        
        //Constructor
        tLista(){
            head = tail = curr = new tNodo;
            listSize = 0;
            pos = 0;
        }
        //Destructor
        ~tLista(){}
        
        int insert(tElemLista item);
        int append(tElemLista item);
        tElemLista erase();
        void moveToStart();
        void moveToPos(unsigned int pos);
        tElemLista getValue();
    
};
```

Definiendo por supuesto el struct tNodo asi:

```
typedef int tElemLista;

struct tNodo{
    tElemLista info;
    tNodo* sig;
};
```

Luego las operaciones para mi implementacion son de la siguiente forma:

```
int tLista::insert(tElemLista item){
    tNodo *aux = curr->sig;

    curr->sig = new tNodo;
    curr->sig->info = item;
    curr->sig->sig = aux;
    if(curr==tail){
        tail = curr->sig;
    }
    listSize++;
    return pos;
}

int tLista::append(tElemLista item){
    curr = tail;
    pos = listSize;
    
    tNodo *aux = curr->sig;
    curr->sig = new tNodo;
    curr->sig->info = item;
    curr->sig->sig = aux;
    tail = curr->sig;
    
    listSize++;
    return pos;
}

tElemLista tLista::erase(){
    tNodo* aux;
    tElemLista num;
    
    if(curr!=tail){
        aux = curr->sig;
        curr->sig = aux->sig;
        num = aux->info;
        delete aux;
        listSize--;
        return num;
    }else{
        cout << "No se realizo ningun cambio, no hay sucesor para eliminar..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}

void tLista::moveToStart(){
    curr = head;
    pos = 0;
}

tElemLista tLista::getValue(){
    if(listSize > 0){
        return curr->info;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

No incluí algunas operaciones ya que creo que el problema no esta en ellas, no se que podría ser la verdad.

De igual forma adjunto un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor:

```cpp
int main(){

    tLista L;

    L.moveToStart();
    cout << L.getValue() << endl; //Esto retorna -1 ya que no hay elementos

    L.insert(2);
    L.append(5);
    L.moveToStart();
    cout << L.getValue() << endl; //Aqui retorna un 0 en vez de un 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sin un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema va a estar difícil que te demos una respuesta

Comment: A parte de que deberías poner un ejemplo mínimo, los problemas que he visto testeando han sido relacionados a que inicializas los 3 nodos al crear la lista, por lo que ya en la primera posición hay un nodo no deseado y el primer nodo que insertas lo haces en la segunda posición, de ahí que cuando llamas a getValue obtienes el nodo que está en current que es la posición 0 y al eliminar eliminas el nodo deseado que estaba en la posición 1, además deberías trabajar más con nullprt en lugar de dejar que los punteros se inicialicen solos y crear nuevos nodos solamente cuando introduzcan valores

Comment: Gracias a ambos por sus comentarios, acabo de añadir un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor.